# Unable to load hyperref and make experiment with labbook.cls

Tags: labbook

I am trying to use the labbook document class and find that I am neither able to load the hyperref package nor make an experiment section.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[hyperref]{labbook}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\labday{27 September 2021}
\experiment[test1]{This is a test experiment}
\end{document}
```

And I get two errors:

```
! Class labbook Error:hyperref option given, but package not loaded.
```

and

```
!Missing \endcsname inserted <to be read again>\let \end{document}
```

I've tried pdflatex as well as xelatex.
My OS is Linux Mint. My frontend is TeXMaker.

Comment: See section 2.1 in the `labbook` manual, you still have to load `hyperref` manually. It is best not to auto load it as (1) it needs to be last and (2) a few packages need to be loaded after `hyperref`

Comment: the class doesn't work in a current latex without patches see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429955/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer didn't that get fixed https://github.com/latex-labbook/labbook/commit/ff14f3ad3e5c8f7be410979e3cfa6e923366c3b6 oh, not at ctan, hmm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have version 2003/05/20 v1.1.

Comment: yes I had forgotten, I wrote to the author in 2018 asking if we could push that fix. No reply:( @UlrikeFischer